typescript generic type alias that returns generic type alias (higher order generic type alias)
well, I'm quite sure that this doesn't possible(yet), but I would ask anyway just to raise the awareness and also just share my thoughts:
let's start by taking example from JavaScript higher order functions:
const power = (num: number, order: number) => {
  return Math.pow(num, order);
};

const power2 = (num: number) => {
  return power(num, 2);
};

here, the existence of power(higher order function), helped us simplify the implementation of power2 'a lot'.
I'm looking for something similar in generic type aliases in typescript.
I'm writing a type wrapper for Expressjs, and I want to reduce the complexity of the types that must be written in the user side, when using my lib.
assume i have a complex type TypedRoutes:
type TypedRoutes = GetRoutesInfo<typeof typedRouter>;
//   ^?
// type TypedRoutes = {
//   "/": {
//       get: (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: IHandlerResponse<[]>) => IHandlerResponse<...>;
//   };
//   "/test": {
//       ...;
//   };
// }

currently, in order to resolve a response of specific route, I'm instructing my users to create generic type alias RoutesResponseResolver on their side using exported internal types from my lib:
import { GetRouteResponseInfo, InferRes} from "express-typed";

type RoutesResponseResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes, Method extends keyof TypedRoutes[Path]> = InferRes<
  GetRouteResponseInfo<typeof typedRouter, Path, Method>
>;

then they can resolve route responses:
type HomeRouteResponse = RoutesResponseResolver<"/", "get">;
//   ^?
//   type HomeRouteResponse = "Typesafe Route!"

full code example(also available here):
import { GetRouteResponseInfo, GetRoutesInfo, InferRes, TypedRouter } from "express-typed";

const typedRouter = new TypedRouter({
  "/": {
    get: (req, res) => {
      return res.send("Typesafe Route!").status(200);
    },
    post: (req, res) => {
      return res.send(req.body).status(200);
    },
  },
  "/test": {
    get: (req, res) => {
      return res.send("TEST! Typesafe Route!").status(200);
    },
  },
});

// export type TypedRoutes = (typeof typedRouter)['routes'];

type TypedRoutes = GetRoutesInfo<typeof typedRouter>;
//   ^?
//   type TypedRoutes = {
//     "/": {
//         get: (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: IHandlerResponse<[]>) => IHandlerResponse<...>;
//         post: (req: Request<...>, res: IHandlerResponse<...>) => IHandlerResponse<...>;
//     };
//     "/test": {
//         ...;
//     };
//   }

type RoutesResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes, Method extends keyof TypedRoutes[Path]> = GetRouteResponseInfo<
  typeof typedRouter,
  Path,
  Method
>;
type RoutesResponseResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes, Method extends keyof TypedRoutes[Path]> = InferRes<
  GetRouteResponseInfo<typeof typedRouter, Path, Method>
>;

type HomeRouteInfo = RoutesResolver<"/", "get">;
type HomeRouteResponse = RoutesResponseResolver<"/", "get">;
//   ^?
//   type HomeRouteResponse = "Typesafe Route!"


export default typedRouter;

note for the complex types i had to instruct my users define on their side because it isn't possible in typescript to return generic type alias from generic type alias.

if higher order type aliased was possible in typescript, instead of writing this on the user side:
import { GetRouteResponseInfo, InferRes } from "express-typed";

type RouteResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes, Method extends keyof TypedRoutes[Path]> = GetRouteResponseInfo<
  typeof typedRouter,
  Path,
  Method
>;
type RouteResponseResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes, Method extends keyof TypedRoutes[Path]> = InferRes<
  GetRouteResponseInfo<typeof typedRouter, Path, Method>
>;

my users could simply write on their side:
import { CreateRouteResolver, CreateRouteResponseResolve } from "express-typed";

type RouteResolver = CreateRouteResolver<
  typeof typedRouter,
>;
type RouteResponseResolve = CreateRouteResponseResolve<
  typeof typedRouter,
>;

and then hide relatively internal type aliases such GetRouteResponseInfo and InferRes.
I know that this is not possible and could maybe need to define a new syntax to declare what parameters the left hand side generic type alias should accept. I could imagine the syntax for declaring higher order type alias as follow, when the parameters that are expected for the returned type alias declared on the left side of the type name:
type <Path extends keyof Router,Method extends keyof Router[Path]>CreateRouteResolver<Router extends TypedRouter> = GetRouteResponseInfo<
  Router,
  Path,
  Method
>;


Self contained example
this code provides minimum example that provides both lib side code and user side ("example usage" section) code. the goal is to simplify RouteResponseResolver on the userside, possibly by implementing CreateRouteResponseResolve type as discussed above.
export type IHandlerResponse<Res extends any[] = []> = {
  status<T>(arg: T): IHandlerResponse<[...Res, { status: T }]>;

  json<const T>(arg: T): IHandlerResponse<[...Res, { json: SendRes<T> }]>;
  send<const T>(arg: T): IHandlerResponse<[...Res, { send: SendRes<T> }]>;
};

type SendRes<T> = { _sentResponse: T };

export type IHandlerRequest<Req extends any[] = []> = {
  body: any;
};

export type HandlerMethods = "all" | "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete" | "patch" | "options" | "head";

export type TypedRouter<
  R extends {
    [key: string]: {
      [key in HandlerMethods]?: (req: IHandlerRequest, res: IHandlerResponse) => void;
    };
  }
> = { routes: R };

export type GetRouteResponseInfo<
  Router extends TypedRouter<any>,
  Path extends keyof Router["routes"],
  Method extends keyof Router["routes"][Path]
> = ReturnType<Router["routes"][Path][Method]> extends IHandlerResponse<infer Res> ? Res : never;

export type InferRes<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? U extends Record<any, infer R extends SendRes<any>>
    ? R["_sentResponse"]
    : never
  : never;

export type Router = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key in HandlerMethods]?: (req: IHandlerRequest, res: IHandlerResponse) => void;
  };
};

////////////////
// example usage
const typedRouter = {
  "/": {
    get: (req, res) => {
      const test = res.send("Typesafe Route!").status(200);
      return test;
    },
  },
  "/test": {
    get: (req, res) => {
      return res.json({ message: 123 }).status(200).send("test");
    },
    post: (req, res) => {
      return res.send(req.body).status(200);
    },
  },
} satisfies Router;

type TypedRoutes = TypedRouter<typeof typedRouter>;

type RouteResponseResolver<Path extends keyof TypedRoutes["routes"], Method extends keyof TypedRoutes["routes"][Path]> = InferRes<
  GetRouteResponseInfo<TypedRoutes, Path, Method>
>;

type HomeRouteResponse = RouteResponseResolver<"/", "get">;
//   ^? "Typesafe Route!"

any suggestions for creative implementations that works around this verbose type declarations on the use side? any known related issue or opened PR for higher order generic type aliases in typesciprt?

• If this question doesn't depend on express, could you [edit] so that the examples don't use it? That way people don't need to add such dependencies to their IDE just to play around with the example code ([mre]). Having the code written in terms of express limits the potential audience. • What specifically is the question, here? SO questions should clearly ask something. Right now it seems like you're saying "This would be nice but I know it's impossible." That's either not a question, or it's one that leads to a "yes this is impossible" answer. That's not really how SO questions work.

I can edit question and remove express from it, but then it just much harder to explain real use case, and then I would just get responses like 'I don't see why this is necessary'.  my hope in this question to get related information such GitHub issue or creative ideas people used to tackle this problem

• You can't explain your use case without a third-party library? I mean, a [mre] generally doesn't pull in technology that's not germane to the topic directly. If your use case is express, maybe you should tag the question with express so that people who know it will see this • At the very least this should ask some kind of question, though. Right now it doesn't seem like any answer is possible.

i understand, i would edit my question

You're possibly looking for ms/TS#1213 but without a standalone [mre] I couldn't possibly make a suggestion with the code as-is, since I don't know enough about express to even get started. I'm not sure if you've decided to tag this with express or to remove express from the example code. Which way do you want to go here?

i've made an edit and removed any express specific code.

• Note that key in is not conventional; that key is a type parameter, not a key name. It should be K or something like it. • Without ms/TS#1213 as linked above, you can't write exactly what you're looking for, as you know.  But: • Does this approach improve things? Instead of type X = H<TypedRoutes>; type Y = X<"/", "get"> you just write type Y = H<TypedRoutes, "/", "get">. It just means you don't get an alias for X, but doing that is more annoying than it's worth, I think. • I can write up an answer unless you think I'm missing something.
